# JMeter JSR233 result to dashboard

Tags: java, testing, groovy, jmeter

I have a JMeter test that insert an input via an HTTP call to an asynchronous java-service and then collects an exposed metric on another java-service via a groovy script.

The script then saves the collected metric as a JMeter variable to be reviewed as a performance metric.

I would like to publish this value inside the JMeter -generated dashboard but I can't find a way to save this variable as a JMeter output.

Is there a way? seems JMeter is primarily aimed to test HTTP synchronous services but it's capable of doing such collection of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable(s) in [custom graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) definitions:

> You can graph any sample_variable in CSV over time, you can customize your graphs by settings their properties in the user.properties file.
>   They must use the id prefix custom_:
>
> ```
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_<your_graph_name_id>.property.<your_option_name>
> ```
>
> To specify that this graph is a customized one :
>
> ```
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_<your_graph_name_id>.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
> ```
>
> Here is an example of a custom graph configuration that graphs the variable ts-hit:
>
> ```
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=Chunk Hit
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=Number of Hits
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=ts-hit
> jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Number of Hits :
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you're saving in the JSR223 script as a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables), in order to do this add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=foo
```

Then you can configure your [custom chart](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) like:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=Your custom chart title
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=Your Y axis name
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=foo
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Your custom content message
```

replace `foo` with the actual JMeter Variable name of your choice and next time you generate HTML reporting dashboard you should see your variable values plotted over time

More information:

- [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)